# Html / css фреймворки

Tags: framework, html, css, фреймворк

Здравствуйте. Нужна ваша помощь.
Не очень понимаю,как нужно работать с фреймворками.
Объясните для чего они нужны и как их использовать.
(фреймворки - [Первый](http://www.yaml.de/), [Второй](http://52framework.com/), ну и не без известный [третий](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)
Спасибо за внимание
С уважением

Comment: Точнее, для чего они нужны я знаю. А вот как пользоваться..

Comment: Как пользоваться написано в документации к фреймворку.

Comment: а русскоязычная документация к этим фреймворкам где-нибудь есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фреймворки нужны для более быстрой/упрощенной разработки приложений. CSS-фреймворк позволяет более быстро создать симпатичный сайтик. Вам не нужно будет самому чего-то там рисовать и не нужно будет думать "какие свойства применить к элементу чтобы он был всё время сверху"(например). За Вас уже всё сделано. Вам остается лишь указать нужному элементу нужный класс(или id).

А если вы не поняли как работать с каждым их этих фреймворков то вперед читать документацию :) Но суть в том, что Вам лишь нужно указывать элементам необходимые классы или id (смотря, что написано в документации)

Comment: @KryDos все правильно описал. Сам я пользуюсь  bootstrap-ом(твиттер), и вполне меня устраивает.

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь html страницу, подключаешь стили фреймворка

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<framework>.css" >
```

И верстаешь страницу используя классы фреймворка.
Как-то так, и ничего сложного